# Webpack(VueJS) make different paths to images for FIrefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, vue.js, webpack

I have VueJS OnePageApplication based on ASP.NET MVC. View realized as .cshtml page without content with plugged VueJS script.
Application placed in IIS, on `localhost/ksodd`.

IIS file structure:

```
wwwroot/ksodd/
- bin
- View/
- Scripts/
-- dist/
--- images/
---- search.png
--- build.js
```

In webpack.config.js i have:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '',
  ...

  module: {
    rules: [
    ...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
          publicPath: './Scripts/dist'
        }
      }
    ...
    ]
  }
```

In vue component:

```
<template>
...
  <img src="../assets/images/search.png">
...
</template>
```

When applcation runs on `localhost` all works fine, but when i run it in IIS as `localhost/ksodd` magic happens:

[image: Firefox]
In firefox image src have wrong path, from root of the site:   `localhost/Scripts/dist/images/search.png`. Returns 404.

[image: Chrome]
In chrome image src have correct path:  `localhost/ksodd/Scripts/dist/images/search.png`. Returns 200.

What is the reason of this, and how i can fix it?
How to make VueJS project, that can work in nested URLs, as in the root of the site?

Comment: My bet is on the subdirectory, did you try to set `publicPath` to `/ksodd` in your Webpack config?

Comment: I want to make application portable, able to work in any directory without rebuilding webpack, but seems your idea is a best way.

Comment: You can have both! https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#environment-based